# Multiple instances of an application, how to close the first and keep the last?

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform, multiple-instances

I want to update an application without any service interruption, the idea is to inform the first instance of the application (aka the **old version**) when the last (aka the **new version**) is ready to start.

**Example:**

1. **old version** is running
2. **new version** starts
3. **new version** detects that **old version** is already running
4. **new version** prepares to serve
5. when ready, **new version** instructs **old version** to close
6. when closed, **old version** informs **new version**
7. **new version** starts serving

When the time comes, the procedure is repeated with a newer version.

This way the service is interrupted for the briefest possible time.

---

My idea was to use a system-wide mutex, unfortunately they are not available in mono, and it's probably not possible to do step 5 with this technique anyway.

Another approach whould be to use a pipe, this is not available on mono too.

My last idea was to use a socket bound to loopback address on a random (constant) port, do you think this is fine or there is a better way to handle situations like mine?

All the code must run on both linux **Mono** and **.NET**.

Thanks for reading, Fabio Iotti.

Comment: It may be little bit overkilling. Which kind of application you're talking about? A service? Something with user interface?

Comment: It's a web server, so a service, a console application whould be fine anyway.

Comment: If there is not user interface (where a close request may wait indefinitely) then I'd simply ask process to terminate (`Process.Close()`) and start waiting (`Process.WaitForExit`). Old version will always serve pending requests before quitting and new version will be pending until done. No need for IPC.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack, but could you just write to a known file

1. Application Starts and checks file for other apps
2. Writes "my id - running" if no app found otherwise write "my id - starting" if another running app is found
3. running app checks file for any new apps marked as starting"
4. If a starting app is found stop service and write "my id - shutdown", then terminate app
5. Starting app will poll file until it finds there are no apps running, then it will start service and write "my id - running"

This looks like a link to a similar issue:

[Simple cross-platform process to process communication in Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366316/simple-cross-platform-process-to-process-communication-in-mono)

Comment: Interesting, I'd avoid polling if possible, anyway.
Thanks for the link.